# What is "[object type]"

Tags: javascript, object, tostring

`toString()` returns "[object type]", so that  `toString.call(new Date)` returns `[object Date]`, and `toString.call(new String)` returns `[object String]`. I am curious what the nature of "[object type]" would be: it could not be an array, as the use of [] implies; if it is an object, wouldn't `{type: object}` be a more informative syntax? If it is a string, why not just return for example "type" where type is the type of the object such as `Date` and `String`?

Comment: There is no particular reason for that behavior, other than that it's what the original implementation did. It just works that way, and it cannot be changed because a massive amount of software relies on it.

Comment: As noted, `toString` returns a string containing an opening bracket, the constructor, the type, and a closing bracket. The brackets have no special meaning, they aren't an array, it's just the way the [**specification**](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.2.4.2) says it should be returned.

Comment: Note what you call "type" is not a [type](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-type). In ES5 it's the internal [[Class]], in ES6 is something more complicated.

Answer (score 3):

That is just what the javascript language specification says the `toString` method should do

1. If the this value is undefined, return "[object Undefined]". If the
   this value is null, return "[object Null]".
2. Let O be the result of calling ToObject passing the this value as
   the argument.
3. Let class be the value of the [[Class]] internal property of O.
4. Return the String value that is the result of concatenating the
   three Strings "[object ", class, and "]".

As [oriol](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1529630/oriol) pointed ECMASCRIPT 2015 (also known as ES6) made the `toString` method a bit more complicated. The way it finds out which object type it deals with is a bit more verbose. You can see the new spec [here](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-object.prototype.tostring)
[Source](https://es5.github.io/#x15.2.4.2)

Comment: Note ES6 removed [[Class]], now it's [a bit more complicated](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-object.prototype.tostring).

Comment: `const letsBreakJQuery = {[Symbol.toStringTag]: 'Array'};` - lets break some libs :)

Comment: @Oriol updated the answer to include a link to the new spec and the way it handles a call to `ToString`

Comment: How is ToObject called? To test I tried: var ob=new Object(); var O=ob.ToObject(this) or var cl=ob.ToObject(this)[[Class]], and got 'ob.ToObject is not a function'.

Comment: @TreefishZhang you have to call `Object.prototype.toString.call(<your object here>)`. For example `let num = 1; Object.prototype.toString.call(num);` gives you `'[object Number]'`

Comment: @eltonkamami: so is 'Object.prototype.toString.call(<your object here>)' a direct interpretation of "2. Let O be ...." and "3. Let class be..."? Those two items seem a little cryptic to me: what does calling ToObject mean? And [[Class]]?